# Blackberry 1251 encoding

Tags: blackberry, encoding, cp1251

Is there a way to convert a byte array to string with the windows-1251 encoding in Blackberry? i tried

```
str = new String(mybyteArr, "Windows-1251");
```

or

```
str = new String(mybyteArr, "Cp1251");
```

but I get **UnsupportedEncodingException**.

I am using Blackberry JRE 5.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported right out of the box in the BB API.

BlackBerry supports the following character encodings:

- "ISO-8859-1"
- "UTF-8"
- "UTF-16BE"
- "US-ASCII"

However if you have an array of bytes and you know this is a string encoded in cp1251, then you may manually create a `String` from it using smth like this:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
char c;
for (int i = 0; i < mybyteArr.length; i++) {
    c = getUnicodeCharForCP1251(mybyteArr[i]);
    sb.append(c);
}

private char getUnicodeCharForCP1251(byte b) {
    // return a matching unicode char for the argument
    // using the table from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251
}
```